# Вопрос о переводе (выбор глагола)

Tags: глаголы, переводы

Оригинал: *I didn't know he was Italian.*

сло́во в сло́во: *Я не знала, что он итальянец.*

Перевод переводчика:
*Никогда бы не подумала, что он – итальянец.*

Для моего уха звучит достаточно акцептабельно. Вот как я понимаю: (1) один персонаж итальянец (факт), другой персонаж не знал это просто до определённого момента. (2) один персонаж даже не мог себе представить, что другой персонаж такой национальности. может он что-то другое предполагал. Mне хотелось бы знать, "нарушает" переводчик что-то; искажает он что-то через выбор другого глагола или все в рамках позволительного?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я против закрытия вопроса. Он не о переводе на самом деле, а о столь любимой грамматике автором грамматике и семантике русского условного (сослагательного) наклонения во всех его испостасях. Перевод тут только повод задуматься.

Comment: uyyy вопрос хотят закрывать? Вы меня правильно понимаете, Sr. Мимоходов! спасибо! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда бы не подумала, что он – итальянец. I never would have thought that he is Italian.

Два разных смысла: (1) я не знала, что он итальянец; (2) я очень удивлена, что он итальянец. И две разных формы в обоих языках.

Поэтому это, конечно,  неточный перевод, но, возможно, переводчик посчитал, что такой вариант  лучше передает смысл сказанного (эмоции, прежде всего) **в той ситуации**, которая описывается в тексте.

Comment: Oh Arina, большое Вам спасибо! Yes, yes, yesssss, тоже так подозревала! =) можно еще вопрос: жонглировала с другими глаголами "никогда бы не подумала/никогда бы не купила/никогда бы не сказала" и глаголы выходят все с завершившимся аспектом. каким агрументом это можно объяснить? это связано как-то с одноразовостью действия?

Comment: Вот еще пример: "Так вы медичка? Никогда бы не подумала! С вашей наружностью!" Смысл здесь такой: Никогда бы не подумала (если бы стала об этом думать) до того момента, пока вы не сказали об этом. Поэтому ирреальное действие выражено глаголом совершенного вида.

Comment: Спасибо! =) PD: что означает "медичка"?

Comment: Значение слова Медичка по Ефремовой: Медичка - женск. к сущ.: медик (о студентке).

Comment: Только порядок должен быть 'I would never...'